# FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay is leaking layouts from random fragment

Tags: android, firebase, memory-leaks, leakcanary, firebase-in-app-messaging

We are using firebase inapp messaging and it seems to leak(as shown by leak canary) multiple things arbitrarily in the app .

This leak sometimes comes up with splash activity,  OTP fragment or anyother things that are part of app initiation .,

Usually leakcanary reports the platform stuff as the Exclude but this doesnt seem to get excluded, surprisingly this there is no code related to inappmessage or firebae in any of these fragments/ activities.

```
        * Details:
    * Instance of com.app.nhs.NHSApplication
    |   static __nhsApplicationContext = com.app.nhs.NHSApplication@1115479984 (0x427cdfb0)
    |   static $staticOverhead = byte[48]@1115478585 (0x427cda39)
    |   static TAG = "NHSApplication"
    |   exoConfig = im.ene.toro.exoplayer.Config@1121658096 (0x42db24f0)
    |   profileId = null
    |   profileObj = null
    |   simpleCache = com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.SimpleCache@1121423792 (0x42d791b0)
    |   mActivityLifecycleCallbacks = java.util.ArrayList@1115480056 (0x427cdff8)
    |   mAssistCallbacks = null
    |   mComponentCallbacks = java.util.ArrayList@1115480032 (0x427cdfe0)
    |   mLoadedApk = android.app.LoadedApk@1115461752 (0x427c9878)
    |   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl@1115551592 (0x427df768)
    * Instance of java.util.ArrayList
    |   static $staticOverhead = byte[48]@1105582689 (0x41e5da61)
    |   static serialVersionUID = 8683452581122892189
    |   static MIN_CAPACITY_INCREMENT = 12
    |   array = java.lang.Object[18]@1122366304 (0x42e5f360)
    |   size = 14
    |   modCount = 16
    * Array of java.lang.Object[]
    |   [0] = com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BackgroundDetector@1116363080 (0x428a5948)
    |   [1] = com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdu@1116698784 (0x428f78a0)
    |   [2] = com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.ForegroundNotifier@1116926112 (0x4292f0a0)
    |   [3] = com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay@1118986552 (0x42b26138)
    |   [4] = com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker$1@1119149432 (0x42b4dd78)
    |   [5] = com.facebook.marketing.CodelessActivityLifecycleTracker$1@1119211992 (0x42b5d1d8)
    |   [6] = com.clevertap.android.sdk.ActivityLifecycleCallback$1@1119831616 (0x42bf4640)
    |   [7] = io.fabric.sdk.android.ActivityLifecycleManager$ActivityLifecycleCallbacksWrapper$1@1120245872 (0x42c59870)
    |   [8] = com.onesignal.ActivityLifecycleListener@1121849392 (0x42de1030)
    |   [9] = io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchActivityLifeCycleObserver@1122149928 (0x42e2a628)
    |   [10] = com.squareup.leakcanary.AndroidHeapDumper$1@1122344520 (0x42e59e48)
    |   [11] = com.squareup.leakcanary.ActivityRefWatcher$1@1122366288 (0x42e5f350)
    |   [12] = com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.FragmentRefWatcher$Helper$1@1122371752 (0x42e608a8)
    |   [13] = com.uxcam.a.a@1123030336 (0x42f01540)
    |   [14] = null
    |   [15] = null
    |   [16] = null
    |   [17] = null
    * Instance of com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.firebaseInAppMessagingDisplay
    |   static $staticOverhead = byte[72]@1116409833 (0x428b0fe9)
    |   static INTERVAL_MILLIS = 1000
    |   static IMPRESSION_THRESHOLD_MILLIS = 5000
    |   static DISMISS_THRESHOLD_MILLIS = 20000
    |   animator = com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.FiamAnimator@1119043488 (0x42b33fa0)
    |   application = com.app.nhs.NHSApplication@1115479984 (0x427cdfb0)
    |   autoDismissTimer = com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.RenewableTimer@1119043440 (0x42b33f70)
    |   bindingWrapperFactory = com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.BindingWrapperFactory@1119043472 (0x42b33f90)
    |   callbacks = null
    |   fiamListener = null
    |   firebaseInAppMessagingDisplay = com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay$1@1128847240 (0x4348d788)
    |   headlessInAppMessaging = com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessaging@1116848760 (0x4291c278)
    |   imageLoader = com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.FiamImageLoader@1118989360 (0x42b26c30)
    |   impressionTimer = com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.RenewableTimer@1119043424 (0x42b33f60)
    |   inAppMessage = null
    |   layoutConfigs = java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap@1118988472 (0x42b268b8)
    |   windowManager = com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.FiamWindowManager@1119043456 (0x42b33f80)
    * Instance of com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay$1
    |   this$0 = com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay@1118986552 (0x42b26138)
    |   val$activity = com.app.nhs.activities.auth.LoginActivity@1135077936 (0x43a7ea30)
    * Instance of com.app.nhs.activities.auth.LoginActivity
    |   TAG = "LoginActivity"
    |   progressDialogFragment = com.app.nhs.util.ProgressDialogFragment@1128844272 (0x4348cbf0)
    |   mDelegate = androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl@1136093920 (0x43b76ae0)
    |   mResources = androidx.appcompat.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources@1136092752 (0x43b76650)
    |   mThemeId = 2131886097
    |   mPendingFragmentActivityResults = androidx.collection.SparseArrayCompat@1118649752 (0x42ad3d98)
    |   mFragments = androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController@1135412416 (0x43ad04c0)
    |   mNextCandidateRequestIndex = 0
    |   mCreated = true
    |   mRequestedPermissionsFromFragment = false
    |   mResumed = false
    |   mStartedActivityFromFragment = false
    |   mStartedIntentSenderFromFragment = false
    |   mStopped = true
    |   mLifecycleRegistry = androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry@1135411496 (0x43ad0128)
    |   mOnBackPressedCallbacks = java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList@1135411832 (0x43ad0278)
    |   mViewModelStore = androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStore@1136101176 (0x43b78738)
    |   mExtraDataMap = androidx.collection.SimpleArrayMap@1135411472 (0x43ad0110)
    |   mActionBar = null
    |   mActivityInfo = android.content.pm.ActivityInfo@1135407952 (0x43acf350)
    |   mAllLoaderManagers = android.util.ArrayMap@1128847128 (0x4348d718)
    |   mApplication = com.app.nhs.NHSApplication@1115479984 (0x427cdfb0)
    |   mWindowManager = android.view.WindowManagerImpl@1136092728 (0x43b76638)
    |   mWindow = com.android.internal.policy.impl.MiuiPhoneWindow@1135414400 (0x43ad0c80)
    |   mUiThread = java.lang.Thread@1105587800 (0x41e5ee58)
    |   mTranslucentCallback = null
    |   mComponent = android.content.ComponentName@1135407688 (0x43acf248)
    |   mToken = android.os.BinderProxy@1135407856 (0x43acf2f0)
    |   mContainer = android.app.Activity$1@1135411312 (0x43ad0070)
    |   mCurrentConfig = android.content.res.Configuration@1135413160 (0x43ad07a8)
    |   mDecor = null
    |   mTitle = "NHS Debug"
    |   mDefaultKeySsb = null
    |   mSearchManager = null
    |   mResultData = null
    |   mEmbeddedID = null
    |   mParent = null
    |   mMenuInflater = null
    |   mFragments = android.app.FragmentManagerImpl@1135411192 (0x43acfff8)
    |   mHandler = android.os.Handler@1135411440 (0x43ad00f0)
    |   mManagedDialogs = null
    |   mInstanceTracker = android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker@1135411352 (0x43ad0098)
    |   mInstrumentation = android.app.Instrumentation@1115474480 (0x427cca30)
    |   mIntent = android.content.Intent@1135407528 (0x43acf1a8)
    |   mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null
    |   mLoaderManager = null
    |   mManagedCursors = java.util.ArrayList@1135411328 (0x43ad0080)
    |   mMainThread = android.app.ActivityThread@1115428224 (0x427c1580)
    |   mLoadersStarted = false
    |   mIdent = 1136558632
    |   mFinished = true
    |   mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = false
    |   mResultCode = 0
    |   mDoReportFullyDrawn = false
    |   mResumed = false
    |   mDestroyed = true
    |   mStartedActivity = false
    |   mStopped = true
    |   mTemporaryPause = false
    |   mDefaultKeyMode = 0
    |   mTitleColor = 0
    |   mTitleReady = true
    |   mConfigChangeFlags = 0
    |   mCheckedForLoaderManager = true
    |   mChangingConfigurations = false
    |   mVisibleFromClient = true
    |   mVisibleFromServer = false
    |   mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
    |   mWindowAdded = true
    |   mCalled = true
    |   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl@1135413768 (0x43ad0a08)
    |   mInflater = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater@1136092288 (0x43b76480)
    |   mOverrideConfiguration = null
    |   mResources = android.content.res.MiuiResources@1115554328 (0x427e0218)
    |   mTheme = android.content.res.Resources$Theme@1136093792 (0x43b76a60)
    |   mThemeResource = 2131886097
    |   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl@1135413768 (0x43ad0a08)
    * Excluded Refs:
    | Field: android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.nextIdle
    | Field: android.widget.Editor$EasyEditSpanController.this$0
    | Field: android.widget.Editor$SpanController.this$0
    | Field: android.os.Message.obj
    | Field: android.os.Message.next
    | Field: android.os.Message.target
    | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mNextServedView
    | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedView
    | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedInputConnection
    | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mCurRootView
    | Field: android.animation.LayoutTransition$1.val$parent
    | Field: android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$1.this$0
    | Field: androidx.appcompat.internal.widget.ActivityChooserModel.mActivityChoserModelPolicy
    | Field: android.widget.ActivityChooserModel.mActivityChoserModelPolicy
    | Field: android.speech.SpeechRecognizer$InternalListener.this$0
    | Field: android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.this$1
    | Field: android.media.MediaScannerConnection.mContext
    | Field: android.os.UserManager.mContext
    | Field: android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$Callbacks.this$0
    | Field: android.media.AudioManager$1.this$0
    | Field: android.widget.Editor$Blink.this$0
    | Field: android.net.ConnectivityManager.sInstance
    | Field: android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.mMessageQueue (always)
    | Static field: android.text.TextLine.sCached
    | Thread:FinalizerWatchdogDaemon (always)
    | Thread:main (always)
    | Thread:LeakCanary-Heap-Dump (always)
    | Class:java.lang.ref.WeakReference (always)
    | Class:java.lang.ref.SoftReference (always)
    | Class:java.lang.ref.PhantomReference (always)
    | Class:java.lang.ref.Finalizer (always)
    | Class:java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference (always)
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to work around this leak?

Comment: no i couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I created an issue at the Firebase SDK on GitHub about the memory leak. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/482